# How can I ensure thread safety in the following context?

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, locking, reentrantlock

I have a method called processOutbox. I want it to be thread safe. I don't want another thread to call this method while one thread is at it. I have implemented it the following way. Have I done it correctly? Are there any loopholes in my implementation? If there are any, then please advice on how I can resolve it.

```
this.start();
    outboxLock.lock();
    timer = new Timer();
    try{
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
               processOutbox();
            }
        }, 0, period);
    } finally{
        outboxLock.unlock();
    }
```

Comment: You only locked the scheduling. The execution is still not threadsafe.

Comment: How do I do it then? Please advice.

Comment: I would suggest to synchronize it on class level static variable.

Comment: @NamanGala So I have removed the implementation in my question. I just made my method synchronized. Shall  I accept the below answer as the answer?

Comment: Use a single-threaded `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Comment: You should not worry about making _methods_ thread safe:  It's the _data_ that need to be protected.  Of course, it's all the same thing when can only be seen by a single method, but that isn't how most programs are designed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to make your method processOutbox, you should use the keyword `synchronized`:

```
public class YourClass{
    public synchronized void processOutbox(){
         //do all you want
    }
}
```

More info at:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

If in your code you have an instance of YourClass called for example `myInstance` , all calls to `processOutbox()` will be thread safe because they will be locked at instance level.

For example:

```
YourClass myInstance = new YourClass();
 Thread thread1 = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
      myInstance.processOutbox();
    }
  }
 Thread thread2 = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
       myInstance.processOutbox();
    }
  }
thread1.start();
thread2.start();
```

Here thead2 will be waiting until thread1 finishes the call to "processOutbox"

But for example:

```
YourClass myInstance = new YourClass();
YourClass myInstance2= new YourClass();
Thread thread1 = new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        myInstance.processOutbox();
    }
};
Thread thread2 = new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        myInstance2.processOutbox();
    }
}
thread1.start();
thread2.start();
```

thead2 will **NOT** wait because they are calling the method on different instances.

Someone specifically asked about using ReentrantLock -- So I'm adding that response on to this one, because this one is correct.

```
public class YourClass {
    private Lock outboxLock = new ReentrantLock();
    public void processOutbox() {
        outboxLock.lock()
        try {
            // do stuff
        } finally {
            outboxLock.unlock()
        }
    }
}
```

I mention this specifically because you can also do things, where you keep other threads out of the lock without causing them to block by using tryLock instead.

```
public class YourClass {
    private Lock outboxLock = new ReentrantLock();
    public void processOutbox() {
        if( outboxLock.tryLock() ) {  
            try {
                // do stuff
            } finally {
                outboxLock.unlock()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **I don't want another thread to call this method while one thread is at it.**

Comment: Java API: "When one thread is executing a synchronized method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first thread is done with the object."

Comment: How can I achieve the same using reentrantlock? please advice goku :)

Comment: If you read it carefully, there it is mention **for an object** and not **for all object**.

Comment: @mayooran - Lock and unlock at the beginning and end of `processOutBox()` respectively. Although *synchornizing* would have the same effect. So, yes, this answer is also correct

Comment: I dont undestand you : "
If you read it carefully, there it is mention for an object and not for all object"

Comment: @TheLostMind If another object/process tries to access the same method, will it allow to access the method? If so how can I not allow other objects to access as well?

Comment: @mayooran - In your current case it is allowing. If you mark the method as synchronized, then it wont.

Comment: If another object/process tries to access the same method" of the same instace", it will not allow to execute until others threads release the lock.

Comment: If I understand the question of the OP, he is asking for exclusive lock for the method. No other object can access the method.

Comment: @NamanGala - And *synchronized* prevents other **threads** from accessing that part of code. It's all about which part of code a thread can access. Locks are just gate keepers

Comment: I might be wrong, but according to my understanding lock is applied on `this` which is the calling object. If same object is used to call the method from different threads then it will work as expected. And as the calling object gets changed, it will allow execution of the method.

Comment: @TheLostMind So I have removed the implementation in my question. I just made my method synchronized. Shall  I accept this answer as the answer?

Comment: I have edited my answer..maybe it will help a bit more now.

Comment: @DavidHerrero what would happen if an object called myInstance2 of "YourClass" tries to access the processOutbox method?

Comment: @NamanGala - Assuming `processOutbox()` to be an *instance level* method. See, using `synchronized` at method level is same as using `synchronized(this) {..}`. The lock will be on the current object. If two threads use 2 different objects to access this method, *the state of those 2 objects will be different*. Thus there will be 2 different locks. Which is fine.

Comment: @mayooran - Objects dont call methods *threads do*. Threads call / execute methods on objects

Comment: @mayooran - This will prevent other threads from executing *synchronized* code if their lock is also on the current object

Comment: @TheLostMind thumps up for your explanation. But I guess @ mayooran wants static synchronized method. @ mayooran do you want only one object in your system to call your method at a time or is it ok if different objects of same class call the method at the same time?

Comment: @NamanGala if he wants **Class** level synchronication instead of **Instance** level syncrhonization he justa have to change the declaration of `processOutBox` to `public static synchronized void processOutbox()`

Comment: @NamanGala - I can't be sure of that unless I see the complete flow and state changes done by that done

Comment: @NamanGala  I added a bit about using tryLock which will cause other threads to leave without processing, but not block, which is what I _think_ you actually want.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) for synchronization.